# Counting occurrences of a sub-string without using a built-in function

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

My teacher challenged me of finding a way to count the occurences of the word "bob" in any random string variable without `str.count()`. So I did,

```
a = "dfjgnsdfgnbobobeob bob"
compteurDeBob = 0
for i in range (len(a) - 1):
   if a[i] == "b":
       if a[i+1] == "o":
           if a[i+2] == "b":
               compteurDeBob += 1
print(compteurDeBob)
```

but I wanted to find a way to do that with a word of any length as shown below, but I have no clue on how to do that...

```
a = input("random string: ")
word = input("Wanted word: ")
compteurDeBob = 0
for i in range (len(a)-1):

   #... i don't know... 

print(compteurDeBob)
```

Comment: What is  a *high* level function?

Comment: Just so you know, you can accept only one answer. Be sure you select the one you believe is the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = input("random string: ")
word = input("Wanted word: ")

count = 0
for i in range(len(a)-len(word)):
    if a[i:i+len(word)] == word:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

If you want your search to be case-insensitive, then you can use `lower()` function:

```
a = input("random string: ").lower()
word = input("Wanted word: ").lower()

count = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i:i+len(word)] == word:
        count += 1
print(count)
```

For the user input

```
Hi Bob. This is bob
```

the first approach will output `1` and the second approach will output `2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use string slicing. One way to adapt your code:

```
a = 'dfjgnsdfgnbobobeob bob'

counter = 0
value = 'bob'
chars = len(value)

for i in range(len(a) - chars + 1):
    if a[i: i + chars] == value:
        counter += 1
```

A more succinct way of writing this is possible via `sum` and a generator expression:

```
counter = sum(a[i: i + chars] == value for i in range(len(a) - chars + 1))
```

This works because `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python, i.e. `True` / `False` values are considered `1` and `0` respectively.

Note `str.count` won't work here, as it [only counts *non-overlapping* matches](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.count). You *could* utilise [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) if built-ins are allowed.

Answer (score 2):

To count all overlapping occurrences (like in your example) you could just slice the string in a loop:

```
a = input("random string: ")
word = input("Wanted word: ")    
cnt = 0

for i in range(len(a)-len(word)+1):
    if a[i:i+len(word)] == word:
        cnt += 1

print(cnt)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to calculate *overlapping* matches is the [*Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) which runs in *O(m+n)* with *m* the string to match, and *n* the size of the string.

The algorithm first builds a lookup table that acts more or less as the description of a *finite state machine (FSM)*. First we construct such table with:

```
def build_kmp_table(word):
    t = [-1] * (len(word)+1)
    cnd = 0
    for pos in range(1, len(word)):
        if word[pos] == word[cnd]:
            t[pos] = t[cnd]
        else:
            t[pos] = cnd
            cnd = t[cnd]
            while cnd >= 0 and word[pos] != word[cnd]:
                cnd = t[cnd]
        cnd += 1
    t[len(word)] = cnd
    return t
```

Then we can count with:

```
def count_kmp(string, word):
    n = 0
    wn = len(word)
    t = build_kmp_table(word)
    k = 0
    j = 0
    while j < len(string):
        if string[j] == word[k]:
            k += 1
            j += 1
            if k >= len(word):
                n += 1
                k = t[k]
        else:
            k = t[k]
            if k < 0:
                k += 1
                j += 1
    return n
```

The above counts overlapping instances in *linear* time in the string to be searched, which was an improvements of the "slicing" approach that was earlier used, that works in *O(m×n)*.

Comment: maybe that's right but far too complicated for me right now, thank you though !